# Communication between mianwindow and dialog in python

Tags: python, dialog, pyqt, communication, attributeerror

Hello I am working on data archive program with python 2.7. I have one mainWindow and there is some elements (Buttons, text lines etc.) Clicking a button open a dialog form page. User select their answer on that dialog page. Dialog page has a button named 'save'. When clicking save button dialog class saving user's selections to database. I want to do, when user clicked to save button on dialog, It will enable some elements on the mainWindow which is not enabled. I am doing this with these codes entering to dialog class and save button function:

self.ui.onceBut.setEnabled(True)    etc.

But I am taking an error:

AttributeError: 'onceDlg' object has no attribute 'onceBut'

onceDlg is dialog pages class name.

How can I solve this and I can do what I want? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Communication between components in Qt are often done using signals and slots, but it's not the only way, and to get a good answer you will have to post more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

`self` in `self.ui.onceBut.setEnabled(True)` refers to dialog, so you get error because your `onceBut` is in your `mainWindow` not in `onceDlg` dialog.

Solution: as @Radio say - Communication between components in Qt are often done using signals and slots, but it's not the only way. 
Easier way is to simply pass main window to dialog window, so you can manipulate with it's buttons, or whatever you want, inside dialog window. In next example I've done that in line `dialog = Dialog(self)`, where `self` refers to `MainWindow` and it is used as `mainWin` inside `Dialog`. Run it, click on first button, dialog will show, click `save` button in dialog and second button in main will be changed and disabled.
I hope I've helped you.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Dialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, mainWin):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self,mainWin)
        self.setWindowTitle(self.tr("Dialog window"))
        self.main = mainWin

        button = QtGui.QPushButton()
        button.setText( "Save (disable dummy button)" )
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.connect(button, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.save)
        self.resize(200, 100)

    def save(self):
        self.main.button2.setEnabled(False)
        self.main.button2.setText( "changed from dialog" )

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()   
        self.setWindowTitle(self.tr("Main window"))

        self.button1 = QtGui.QPushButton()
        self.button2 = QtGui.QPushButton()
        self.button1.setText( "Open dialog" )
        self.button2.setText( "Dummy" )

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.button1)
        layout.addWidget(self.button2)
        self.window = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.window.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.window);

        self.connect(self.button1, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.showDialog)
        self.resize(360, 145)

    def showDialog(self):
        dialog = Dialog(self)
        dialog.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show();
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```